# How to control other element when radio button is check on css?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

How do I change other element when radio button is checked?
I used (~) symbol in my CSS code but it does nothing
here is my code:

```css
.pay{
    cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.check input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
}
/*These are the code i want to work*/
.check input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .pay{
    background: gray;
  color: #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="row check">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="wallet" class="pay">E wallet
                            <input type="radio" id="wallet" name="pay" value="wallet" checked="checked"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="walk" class="pay">Walk In
                            <input type="radio" id="walk" name="pay" value="walk"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You will not be able to target the previous / parent element using css selectors which is presumably what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I want to change the background color of .pay when radio button is check just to have customization for my radio butoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the `label.pay` after the `radio` button then I think your css does what you intended.

```css
.pay{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.check input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
}
/*These are the code i want to work*/
.check input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .pay{
    background: gray;
    color: #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="row check">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="radio" id="wallet" name="pay" value="wallet" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="wallet" class="pay">E wallet</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="radio" id="walk" name="pay" value="walk"/>
    <label for="walk" class="pay">Walk In</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

'~' these little squigglies only apply to sibling containers that follow, rewrite your html as follows and you are good to go!

```
<div class="row check">    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="radio" id="wallet" name="pay" value="wallet" checked="checked"/>
      <label for="wallet" class="pay">E wallet</label>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="radio" id="walk" name="pay" value="walk"/>
      <label for="walk" class="pay">Walk In</label>
    </div> </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bwczegym/5/

Answer (score 0):

--Try this--

```
<div class="row check">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <!-- here get the input out of the label tag and make it over it -->
        <input type="radio" id="wallet" name="pay" value="wallet" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="wallet" class="pay">E wallet</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
         <!-- here get the input out of the label tag and make it over it -->
        <input type="radio" id="walk" name="pay" value="walk"/>
        <label for="walk" class="pay">Walk In</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.